# Android QuickReturn Pattern with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to place a view above a RecyclerView which scrolls away with the RecyclerView and scrolls immediatly down with a down scroll. I know this behavior as quick return but it was implemented for Listview. I know some similiar can be done with CoordinatorLayout But all samples do something with the toolbar. What i want is done in the eBay App.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to set up a `CoordinatorLayout` with an embedded `AppBarLayout` that contains a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that wraps a `Toolbar` and a sibling `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout`. It is the sibling `ViewGroup` that will slide behind the toolbar. The other key is to set up the appropriate scroll flags on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways`.

Here is a short video of the result:

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:expanded="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.0">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is line #1 of the sliding layout..." />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is line #2 of the sliding layout..." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="example.com.myapp.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For exitUntilCollapse to work I had to specify minHeight into the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try using ScrollView to wrap the RcyclerView and the QuickReturn layout.

for smooth scrolling use-

```
recyclerview.setFocusable(false);
recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```